# Passing volley image to the next activity

Tags: android, json, android-volley

been stuck on this small problem for  while now.It's simple but confuses me.I have my first activty as a listview downloaded json data using volley,on clicking you go to the details activty,like below
[image]

i'm able to send the title to the details activty but cannot resolve on the passingthe image too.
Here is my first activty:

```
public class Movies extends ActionBarActivity{
    // Log tag
    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    private static String Title="title";
    private static String bitmap="thumbnailUrl";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.event);

     getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    Intent newActivity2=new Intent();
    setResult(RESULT_OK, newActivity2);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, movieList);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    // Showing progress dialog before making http request
    pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    pDialog.show();

    // changing action bar color
    getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
            new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

    // Creating volley request obj
    JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                    // Parsing json
                    for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                        try {

                            JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                            Movie movie = new Movie();
                            movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                            movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                            movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                    .doubleValue());
                            movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                            // Genre is json array
                            JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                            ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                            }
                            movie.setGenre(genre);

                            // adding movie to movies array
                            movieList.add(movie);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }

                    // notifying list adapter about data changes
                    // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    if (error instanceof NoConnectionError){
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Bummer..There's No Internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }};
            });

    // Adding request to request queue
ParseApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){ 

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) { 
            String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title))
                    .getText().toString();

            Intent intent = new Intent(Movies.this, Detail.class);    
            intent.putExtra(Title, name);
            intent.putExtra("images", bitmap);

            startActivity(intent);
        }
        });}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}



    }
```

**Details activity**

```
public class Detail extends ActionBarActivity{
    private static String Title="title";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.detail);
     getSupportActionBar().hide();

    Intent i=getIntent();
    String name = i.getStringExtra(Title);
    TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);

    lblName.setText(name);}


    public void onClickHandler(View v){
            switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.imageview1:
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Movies.class));
        }

}}
```

i'll post more code if needed.I'm a newbie at this stuff so any help will be appreciated.

CustomListAdapter:

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Movie> movieItems;
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();

public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Movie> movieItems) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.movieItems = movieItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return movieItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return movieItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

    if (imageLoader == null)
        imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
    TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView rating = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.rating);
    TextView genre = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.genre);
    TextView year = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.releaseYear);

    // getting movie data for the row
    Movie m = movieItems.get(position);

    // thumbnail image
    thumbNail.setImageUrl(m.getThumbnailUrl(), imageLoader);

    // title
    title.setText(m.getTitle());

    // rating
    rating.setText("Rating: " + String.valueOf(m.getRating()));

    // genre
    String genreStr = "";
    for (String str : m.getGenre()) {
        genreStr += str + ", ";
    }
    genreStr = genreStr.length() > 0 ? genreStr.substring(0,
            genreStr.length() - 2) : genreStr;
    genre.setText(genreStr);

    // release year
    year.setText(String.valueOf(m.getYear()));

    return convertView;
}

}
```

Comment: I have followed the same tutorial, but i would like to pass integer, double and array list. How would i do that?

Comment: You can try  `String mytext3 = String.valueOf(.....);` before you call intent,then pass `intent.putExtra(Rate, rate);` as an extra.

Comment: Okay, and i need to locate textView of rating? Could you eloberate more about passing this double value to another activity?

Comment: Hello Steve, i have successed and what about realease year of movie(integer) and ArrayList or genres in this case?

Comment: For the arraylist i dont think you need to pass it,just initialize the arraylist on your onCreate method of the activity you want the arraylist to appear

Comment: Please post this as a question i elaborate further,tag me the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to retrieve the thumbnail url in your details page like this

```
String bitmap = i.getStringExtra("images"); // Use this in details page
```

now you can use this `bitmap` to load the image in you details page.

**EDIT**

Use this in `onItemClick()` in `Movies` class

```
bitmap = ((Movie)movieList.get(position)).getThumbnailUrl();
Intent intent = new Intent(Movies.this, Detail.class);    
intent.putExtra(Title, name);
intent.putExtra("images", bitmap);
```

Add this in your `Detail` activity `onCreate()`

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
String bitmap = i.getStringExtra("images");
thumbNail.setImageUrl(bitmap, imageLoader);
```

Comment: using your  code i get error on `thumbNail.setImageBitmap(bitmap);}` .It says `setImageBitmap` in the type ImageView is not applicable for the arguments (String).

Comment: Of course it would. You are passing url of image to the details activity which is String not bitmap.

Comment: yes i see it,what method do i use instead of `setImageBitmap`?

Comment: How are you loading images in the listview? Which method you are using?

Comment: i have included my CustomListAdapter in my edited question, which provides data to my list view.Is that sufficient?

Comment: is that sufficient enough?

Comment: the first part worked thanks,but i'm getting errors on `AppController` as it cannot be resolved to a type,and `setImageUrl` is undefined for the type ImageView.Are we missing something?

Comment: Have you imported `AppController` the way you are using it in the adapter? Also `thumbNail` should be of type `NetworkImageView` the way you are using in adapter's `getView()` method. `thumbNail` is the `NetworkImageView` in detial activity where you want to load the image.

Comment: Yes i have imported `AppController` and replaced `ImageView` with `NetworkImageView` and it has worked.However the image is still not showing.i updated My details xml on my question.Probably where the error is from.

Comment: this is NetworkImage item in details xml.`<com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView
   android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />`

Comment: Check if the image url you are getting in the details page is correct.

Comment: you are a god!!It has worked completely.Thank you so much man!!

Answer (score 1):

You are not retreiving the bitmap in Details Activity:

```
Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) i.getParcelableExtra("images");
```

And then do whatever your need with that bitmap

Comment: His bitmap variable is `String` actually. Little misleading!  :D

Comment: @Álvaro Pérez Soria The image is not loading on details activty,check this link for more code [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/)

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same code but I'm using in fragment. Some one tell how to pass a JSON value from fragment to activity. I want Lastest_fragment.java to News_Detail.java (new activity)

```
Lastest_Fragment.java

public class LatestFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = LatestFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    // Movies json url
    private static final String url = "http://api.androidhive.info/json/movies.json";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private List<Movie> movieList = new ArrayList<Movie>();
    private ListView listView;
    private CustomListAdapter adapter;
    private static String Title="title";
    private static String bitmap="thumbnailUrl";


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.latest_layout, container, false);

        Intent intent2 = new Intent();
       getActivity().setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent2);
       // getActivity().finish();

        listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), movieList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        // changing action bar color
       // getActivity().getActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable( new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1b1b1b")));

        // Creating volley request obj
        JsonArrayRequest movieReq = new JsonArrayRequest(url,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        hidePDialog();

                        // Parsing json
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {

                                JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Movie movie = new Movie();
                                movie.setTitle(obj.getString("title"));
                                movie.setThumbnailUrl(obj.getString("image"));
                                movie.setRating(((Number) obj.get("rating"))
                                        .doubleValue());
                                movie.setYear(obj.getInt("releaseYear"));

                                // Genre is json array
                                JSONArray genreArry = obj.getJSONArray("genre");
                                ArrayList<String> genre = new ArrayList<String>();
                                for (int j = 0; j < genreArry.length(); j++) {
                                    genre.add((String) genreArry.get(j));
                                }
                                movie.setGenre(genre);

                                // adding movie to movies array
                                movieList.add(movie);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }

                        // notifying list adapter about data changes
                        // so that it renders the list view with updated data
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                if (error instanceof NoConnectionError){
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity().getBaseContext(), "Bummer..There's No Internet connection!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
       AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
        //ParseApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(movieReq);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title)).getText().toString();
                    bitmap = ((Movie)movieList.get(position)).getThumbnailUrl();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), News_Detail.class);
                    intent.putExtra(Title, name);
                    intent.putExtra("images", bitmap);

                   startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
        return v;

        }


News_detail.java

public class News_Detail extends AppCompatActivity {

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");

    private static String Title="title";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.news_detail);
        getSupportActionBar().hide();

        Intent i = getIntent();
        ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
        String name = i.getStringExtra(Title);
        String bitmap = i.getStringExtra("images");
        NetworkImageView thumbNail = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.thumbnail);
        thumbNail.setImageUrl(bitmap, imageLoader);
        TextView lblname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_label);

        lblname.setText(name);
    }

    public void onClickHandler(View v){
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.thumbnail:startActivity(new Intent(this,LatestFragment.class));
        }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all enter that code in your fragment activity ...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ItemContents.class);

intent.putExtra("Position", position);

ShopsModel item = (ShopsModel) adapter.getItem(position);
intent.putExtra("logo", item.getThumbnailUrl());
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now paste that code in the next activity where you want to show text and image

```
NetworkImageView img = (NetworkImageView) findViewById(R.id.tv_ic_thumbnail);
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
String bitmap = intent.getStringExtra("logo");
img.setImageUrl(bitmap, imageLoader);
```

Comment: Please do not split your answer into two distinct posts. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27822352/edit) the first one, copy the content of this post into the first one and then delete this one. Otherwise both may get flagged and removed.

Comment: I've merged both posts in your other answer and flagged this one for removal